# Schwarzschild half-plane and its geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

For some fixed $r_0>0,$ put the semi-Riemannian metric 
$$
ds^2=\frac{r_0-r}{r}dt^2+\frac{r}{r-r_0}dr^2
$$
on $\{(t,r)\in\mathbb{R}^2:r>r_0\}.$ I would like to show that the $r$-lines are always geodesics. My problem is I don't know the definition of an $r$-line. I've computed all the Christoffel symbols (and I'm sure my computations are correct) and assumed that an $r$-line is simply a vertical line but it doesn't satisfy the geodesic differential equations. I've even assumed that an $r$-line is horizontal line but I failed again in showing that those lines satisfy the geodesic differential equations. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and/or what the definition of an $r$-line is? Thank you.

Comment: Can it be that an $r$-line is a curve on the $(r,t)$ plane going through every $t$ with $r=const$?

Comment: These are exactly the horizontal lines that I was talking about. They don't satisfy the geodesic differential equations.

Comment: The map $t \mapsto -t$ appears to be an isometry of your space, so it had better send geodesics to geodesics; since it fixes the vertical tangent vector $\partial_r$ at points of the form $(0,r)$, it must fix the geodesic through such vectors; but the fixed set of this isometry is the vertical line $t = 0$, so that line must be a geodesic. Since $t \mapsto t + a$ is also an isometry, all the vertical lines $t = a$ must be geodesics. (I don't know whether this is what's meant by "$r$-line".)

Comment: @mollyerin Thanks. This answers the question. But what I don't understand is that why a line of the form $\gamma(s)=(a,s)$ for all $s>r_0$ doesn't satisfy the geodesic differential equations. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The parameterization $\gamma(s) = (a,s)$ is not a geodesic because $||\gamma'(s)||$ is not constant. (It might be more precise to say that vertical lines are the images of geodesics.) If you parameterize your $\gamma$ by arc length you should get something that does satisfy the geodesic equations.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you so much one more time. Everything is completely clear now.